# $\operatorname{ad}(L)$ is semisimple for a Lie algebra $L$

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

This must be really obvious. But I have $L$ a semisimple Lie algebra $$\begin{array}{rccc}\operatorname{ad}\colon&L&\longrightarrow&GL(L)\\&X&\mapsto&\left(\begin{array}{rccc}\operatorname{ad}(X)\colon&L&\longrightarrow&L\\&Y&\mapsto&\operatorname{ad}(X)(Y) = [X,Y]\end{array}\right)\end{array}$$

Why is $\operatorname{ad}(L)$ semisimple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the adjoint representation has kernel $Z(L)$, which is zero for a semisimple Lie algebra $L$, we have $L\cong ad(L)$ in this case.

Comment: Using first isomorphism theorem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If $L$ is semisimple, $\text{ad}(L)$ is isomorphic to $L$.